# How to force Talkback to speak a specific word when a fragment/activity is shown using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to provide a specific string to Talkback to speak a specific word when a fragment/activity is shown.
I noticed Talkback selects the first UI from top/left to bottom/right to focus however I'd like to force Talkback to speak the title of the screen (there are case there is no UI for screen title but I thought Talkback could speak it anyways since I provide a string). Another note: I'm using Jetpack Compose and thought I could do that somehow using semantics?